# AngularJS filter by two fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to use analogously code to filter my tasks, but it doesn't work properly. If I'm using only one filter than it's ok ( no matter which one I'm using ). but when I try to filter by second input it just doesn't work.

Moreover: when I delete string from first input and than try to filter by second it doesn't work at all.

```
<div>
    Filters: <br />
    Company: <input ng-model="search.project.company.name_company"> <br />
    project: <input ng-model="search.project.project_name"> <br />
</div>
<table>
    <th>Lp.</th>
    <th ><a href="" ng-click="sortBy='project.company.name_company'">Company</a></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy='project.project_name'">project</a></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy='time_start'">Time start</a></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy='time_stop'">Time stop</a></th>
    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortBy='time_start-time_stop'">Work time</a></th>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:search | orderBy:sortBy " class="thumbnail">
        <td >{[{ $index+1 }]}</td>
        <td >{[{ task.project.company.name_company }]}</td>
        <td >{[{ task.project.project_name }]}</td>
        <td >{[{ task.time_start | date : 'y-MM-dd HH:mm' }]}</td>
        <td >{[{ task.time_stop | date : 'y-MM-dd HH:mm' }]}</td>
        <td>{[{ timediff(task.time_start,task.time_stop) }]} godzin</td>
        <td><button ng-click="edit(task)">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button ng-click="delete(task)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/vdkfNkgpdLUp9RgZ1IvO?p=preview

Comment: Can you post a plunk? do you mean it only filters by "search" but does not sort by "sortBy" ?

Comment: nope, sort by works good, search filter is the one that doesn't work well. As You see there are two models to filter by search.

Comment: Is it not possible to have all the properties to be searched name_company and project_name to be at the same level? as in, properties on the search object? The answer I posted should work, if it does not, getting both these fields to be at the same level - properties of the same object will def. fix this issue.

Comment: I've added plunker, it works there exactly like it works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the search properties one level higher on the `search` object? Instead of

```
<input ng-model="search.project.company.name_company"> <br />
    project: <input ng-model="search.project.project_name"> <br />
```

use:

```
<input ng-model="search.company.name_company"> <br />
    project: <input ng-model="search.project_name"> <br />
```

OR
try switching the filter from

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:search | orderBy:sortBy " class="thumbnail">
```

to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter:search.project | orderBy:sortBy " class="thumbnail">
```

or just write a custom filter.

Comment: I modified your plunk so that I flatten the data and the search fields and it seems to be working now. Not sure if flattening is an option for you, but i do not think the search works on multi-level filter. It expects an object map and it will match all the properties on that object.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vdkfNkgpdLUp9RgZ1IvO